# MongoDB & Mongoose: How to find and remove a large group of documents. findAndModify(..... {remove:true})?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Bear with me as I'm pretty new to MongoDB and mongoose has been my only interaction with it. So apologize ahead of time if I'm not properly separating the two technologies or understanding either.

I have a collection that is basically a log. Each log item is the result of a status check on a specific server that I have in my system. When I delete a server I'd like to also remove all the associated log entries. Whats the most efficient way to do this? I know I can find all the log items with a specific server id then iterate through each and remove it but that seems really inefficient. I've read through most of the mongo documentation and it looks like findAndModify is the best way to do this but I can't figure out syntax for this with mongoose. Any chance someone could help me out?

I'm using the latest version on mongoose at the moment, 1.7.2

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Removing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why not just do

```
db.logs.remove({serverid: deletedServerId})
```

?

Comment: *Face palm*

I knew it was something simple like this. Thank you!

Comment: should this be better? findOneAndRemove